# value_counts return float in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to count values in `dataframe` based on some conditions and create `dataframe` from `series` which I got from `value_counts()` I don't know why, but it returns `int` sometimes and `float` sometimes... I would like to normalize everything to `int` and add first empty `column` name in my `dataframe` after `concat`

```py
data = base.get_shuukeihyou(data_from=date_from, data_to=date_to, name=name_field)
sougou_call = data['charge'].value_counts()


data_tsunagatta = data[data.status != "gen"]
data_tsunagatta = data_tsunagatta[data_tsunagatta.status != "empty"]
data_tsunagatta = data_tsunagatta['charge'].value_counts()


apo = data[data.status == "apo"]
apo = apo['charge'].value_counts()

        
kontakuto = data[data.contact != "info"]
kontakuto = kontakuto[kontakuto.contact != "another"]
kontakuto = kontakuto['charge'].value_counts()


alls = pd.concat([sougou_call, data_tsunagatta, apo, kontakuto], axis=1)
alls = alls.fillna(0)
alls.columns = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
print(alls)
```

return this

```
           one  two  three  four
bbbb aaaa      2    0.0 0.0      0.0
john smith          1    1.0 0.0      1.0
```

and I want this

```
  name       one    two   three    four
bbbb aaaa      2     0      0       0
john smith     1     1      0       1
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset the index and use the new [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) method.

```
>>> df
            one  two  three  four
bbbb aaaa     2  0.0    0.0   0.0
john smith    1  1.0    0.0   1.0
>>> df.index.name = 'name'
>>> df.reset_index().convert_dtypes()
         name  one  two  three  four
0   bbbb aaaa    2    0      0     0
1  john smith    1    1      0     1
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! Have an idea how to add first column name? I have nothing there now